# how to install mysql version 8.0.21 using ansible

Tags: mysql, automation, ansible

I am trying to install MySQL version 8.0.21 using ansible. I have downloaded the required tar file from the MySQL community and tried to install using dpkg command but found issues while passing passwords.

```
- name: Set MySQL root password before installing
  debconf: name='mysql-server' question='mysql-server/root_password' value='{{MySQL_root_pass | quote}}' vtype='password'
  become: yes

- name: Confirm MySQL root password before installing
  debconf: name='mysql-server' question='mysql-server/root_password_again' value='{{MySQL_root_pass | quote}}' vtype='password'
  become: yes

- name: Install my_package
  apt: deb="required_package.deb"
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
```

This is my YAML.The mysql version is installed with an empty password

Answer (score 0):

What about the role from [geerlingguy](https://github.com/geerlingguy)

```
ansible-galaxy install geerlingguy.mysql
```

After installing you yml like this:

```
- hosts: YOUR_SERVER_IP_HERE
 
  become: yes
 
  vars_files:
 
    - vars/main.yml
 
  roles:
 
    - { role: geerlingguy.mysql }
 
  pre_tasks:
 
    - name: Install the MySQL repo.
 
      yum:
 
        name: http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
 
        state: present
 
      when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat"
 
    - name: Override variables for MySQL (RedHat).
 
      set_fact:
 
        mysql_daemon: mysqld
 
        mysql_packages: ['mysql-server']
 
        mysql_log_error: /var/lib/mysql/error.log
 
        mysql_syslog_tag: mysqld
 
        mysql_pid_file: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 
        mysql_socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
 
      when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat"
```

Make sure to updat the `vars/main.ym`l file including the version you wish!

Comment: Thanks for ur time. I am using an ubuntu machine and i need the exact mysql version 8.0.21 . How to install the exact version , Where do i mention it?